# Duck the audio of other apps on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, audio, wasapi

I am attempting to activate the Windows default automatic audio ducking: `mmsys.cpl` -> "Communications tab", inside my C++ desktop app so that I can duck only the audio of the rest of the applications but not that of mine so that any important audio is heard and not overlapped by a background such.

The problem is that I not only duck the audio of the rest of the applications - Spotify, browser's audio like YouTube, but also that of my application.

I have extracted the audio ducking functionality from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/coreaudio/duckingcapturesample) Microsoft example which can be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/audio/DuckingCaptureSample).

The most obvious way to notice that the audio of the current application is also ducked is to set the audio ducking setting inside the Windows sound settings to "Mute all other sounds" as shown [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/windows-11-system-settings-sound-q.jpg).

The audio ducking example provided above simulates a communication session/activity as far as I know - a WASAPI chat. I presume this is the reason that my audio is ducked as well since despite being my app opens a communication stream still this sample communication activity from the Microsoft's example is probably overriding my app's audio in terms of priority. That is just a presumption/hypothesis. Presumably something should be changed in [this](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/audio/DuckingCaptureSample/WasapiChat.Cpp) part of the example's code.

I am open to all suggestions what should be fixed/changed/added. I confirm again that I want to use so-called "automatic" or I would say ready-made integrated audio ducking provided by Windows - the one shown on the screenshot above. I don't want to provide a custom ducking behavior by lowering the other apps volume to arbitrary levels.

There are two APIs that directly mention the audio ducking:
[IAudioSessionControl2::SetDuckingPreference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audiopolicy/nf-audiopolicy-iaudiosessioncontrol2-setduckingpreference)
[IAudioClientDuckingControl::SetDuckingOptionsForCurrentStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-iaudioclientduckingcontrol-setduckingoptionsforcurrentstream)

The first one only switches between the automatic ducking behavior and a custom one i.e. switch the automatic off. I am currently testing the second one. The problem with it is the [minimum required](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-iaudioclientduckingcontrol-setduckingoptionsforcurrentstream#requirements) Windows version.

Comment: Please if you downvote the question share why.

Comment: That's strange. Those links are just for help and guidance and reference for the addressed content. I have provided them so that to help others fully explain my investigation.

Comment: Also, for some strange reason I am unable to edit the question - the submitted changes don't appear.

Comment: Probably people are downvoting because they want to see a runnable code in the question itself, as text (a [mcve]). Can you add that?

Comment: I looked at the code from the external link. It's way too large (thousands of lines of code) to add to a question and with lots of winapi GUI code that are not needed. I did not spend enough time to see how difficult it would be to separate out the audio code from the GUI example code.

Comment: Yes I would submit the extracted version of the ducking functionality but it is just a stripped off version of the WasapiChat.cpp + WasapiChat.h from the DuckingCaptureSample above.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the minimal code that triggers the audio ducking:

```
CComPtr<IMMDeviceEnumerator> deviceEnumerator;
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(
    __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator),
    nullptr,
    CLSCTX_ALL /* CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER */,
    IID_PPV_ARGS(&deviceEnumerator));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return;
}

CComPtr<IMMDevice> communicationsDevice;
hr = deviceEnumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(
            eRender, // eCapture for microphone
            eCommunications,
            &communicationsDevice);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return;
}

CComPtr<IAudioClient3> audioClient;
hr = communicationsDevice->Activate(
        __uuidof(IAudioClient3),
        CLSCTX_ALL /* CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER */,
        nullptr,
        reinterpret_cast<LPVOID*>(&audioClient));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return;
}

WAVEFORMATEX* mixFormat = nullptr;
hr = audioClient->GetMixFormat(&mixFormat);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return false;
}

hr = audioClient->Initialize(
        AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED,
        AUDCLNT_SESSIONFLAGS_DISPLAY_HIDE
        | AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_EVENTCALLBACK
        | AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_NOPERSIST,
        500000,
        0,
        mixFormat,
        nullptr);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return;
}

CoTaskMemFree(mixFormat);
mixFormat = nullptr;

hr = audioClient->Start();
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    return;
}
```

Additionally, there are buffer manipulations - both initial and on a separate thread but they don't seem to be part of the minimum requirements to trigger the audio ducking.

Comment: The problem with this code as mentioned above is that it not only ducks the rest of the audio from the other apps but also the current application's one.